# Nginx uniq session and clear cookie

Tags: nginx, session, flask

Im using nginx to redirect my API code and apache guacamole.
i have an issue that i need to use multiuser connection but if im logged in to Auser and i try to connect to Buser ( same browser) it try to reconnect to Auser even if the URL is complitly different :

Auser:

```
https://myapp/#/client/MjIyAGMAcG9zdGdyZXNxbA==/?username=Auser&password=vDeMsKqCG5F
```

Buser:

```
https://myapp/#/client/NTQxAGMAcG9zdGdyZXNxbA==/?username=Buser&password=0aiOMa4o08pb
```

nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    keepalive_timeout  600;


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    #tcp_nopush     on;


    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

nginx/mysite.template:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        server_name reverse.proxy
        server_tokens off;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://guacamole:8080/guacamole/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header        Cookie "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /;
        access_log on;
        client_max_body_size 4096m;
        }

        location /api {
        proxy_pass              http://api:5001/;
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header        Cookie "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        access_log on;
        client_max_body_size 4096m;
        }
}
```

Tried maybe to delete the cookies by :

```
    proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header        Cookie "";
```

but same result.
how can i make ngnix to give uniq session to each request? to ignor user that is alreat connectd.
maybe its the chrome broser issue for shering session data but can nginx settings help here ?

Comment: `#whatever` part is never sent to server. That means server see two identical urls `https://myapp`

Comment: so what can i do ? so it will consider the rest of the URI ?  @AlexeyTen